# Referencing the instance of my main class from other class in java

Tags: java, arraylist, instance

My question is: how do I reference the instance of my main class from a second class in order to get the private field of my main class?

I have 4 classes:

- ValuablesRegister (contains main method)
- Valuables (super class of different valuables)
- ValuablesList (contains an arraylist of valuables and method for iterating)
- Window (creates GUI and has inner classes for actionlisteners)

This is my ValuablesRegister class, which initializes an instance of ValuablesList in a field and creates an instance of Window in the main method:

```
import java.util.*;
    public class ValuablesRegister {

    private ValuablesList currentValuablesList = new ValuablesList("Register");

    private void runApplication() {
        currentValuablesList.addValuables(some values here)
        currentValuablesList.returnValues();
        new Window();

    }

    public ValuablesList getCurrentList() {
        return currentValuablesList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ValuablesRegister().runApplication();
    }

}
```

This is my ValuablesList class, containing the actual arraylist of Valuables-objects:

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class ValuablesList {

        private String listName;
        private ArrayList<Valuables> valuablesList = new ArrayList<Valuables>();
        public ValuablesList(String name) {
            this.listName = name;
        }

        public void addValuable(Valuables v) {
            valuablesList.add(v);
        }

        public void returnValues() {
            for(Valuables v : valuablesList) {
                System.out.println(v.toString());

            }
        }

        public ArrayList<Valuables> getList() {
            return valuablesList;           
        }
    }
```

Finally I have my Window class, which has inner classes for the actionlisteners.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Window extends JFrame {

private JTextArea contentList = new JTextArea();

    public Window() {
        super("Valuables Register");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel north = new JPanel();
        add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JLabel titel = new JLabel("Valuables Register");
            north.add(titel);   
            contentList.setEditable(false);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentList); 
            add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JButton show = new JButton("Show");
            show.addActionListener(new showListener());
            south.add(show);        

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000, 800);
        setVisible(true);

    }





class showListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave) {
        ArrayList<Valuables> list = SOME FUNCTION TO GET THE REFERENCE TO THE ARRAYLIST;
        valuablesAppend(list);
    }
}


private void valuablesAppend(ArrayList<Valuables> valuablesList) {
    for (Valuables v : valuablesList) {
        contentList.append(v.toString());
        contentList.append("\n");
    }
}

}
```

So what I want to happen is the following:

1. User presses the "Show" button
2. The actionPerformed-method of the inner class "showListener" is called.
3. The actionPerformed method calls some method to get the reference to instance of ValuablesList created in the main class ValuablesRegister (currentValuablesList).
4. The actionperformed method calls the ValuablesAppend method which iterates over the ArrayList of valuables objects and calls their toString-method and appends it's String value to the JTextArea.

The problem is I don't know how to get the reference to the arraylist containing these objects. I tried creating a get-method in my ValuablesRegister-class (getCurrentList), but I don't know how to call this method as I don't understand how to reference the instance of my main class. Or should it be done another way?

I was thinking that a possible solution would be to pass the instance of ValuablesRegister to the constructor of Window, and saving it in a field of private field of Window, but I am unsure of how to do this as Window(this); does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it by passing the instance of the main class in the constructor of the Window class. This is how I did it:

Change the Window class by adding a field and setting it in the constructor:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Window extends JFrame {
private JTextArea contentList = new JTextArea();
private ValuablesRegister main;

    public Window(ValuablesRegister mainClass) {
        super("Valuables Register");
        this.main = mainClass;
```

And then passing it with "this" in the ValuablesRegister:

```
private void runApplication() {
    currentValuablesList.addValuable(some values here)
    currentValuablesList.returnValues();
    new Window(ValuablesRegister.this);
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is actually very simple to solve your problem. You just have to give the `Window` class a reference to your `ArrayList`:

Alright, this is the `main` method of the class `Application`. At first, I just initialise the `Window`, just like you did, but using an instance of the `JFrame` instead of inheriting it.

```
public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        final Application instance = new Application();
        final Valuable valuable00 = new Valuable() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "I'm very valuable.";
            }
        };
        final Valuable valuable01 = new Valuable() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "I'm not very valuable.";
            }
        };
        final ValuablesList register = new ValuablesList("Register", 2);
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("StackOverflow");
        register.getList().add(valuable00);
        register.getList().add(valuable01);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(1000, 800);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            if (instance.initialiseUserInterface(frame, register)) {
                System.out.println("Successfully initialised the user interface.");
            }
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
```

The `initialiseUserInterface` method takes two arguments: a reference to the `JFrame`, as well as a reference to the `ValuablesList` object from the `main` method.

```
    public boolean initialiseUserInterface(final JFrame reference, final ValuablesList register) {
        final JPanel north = new JPanel(), south = new JPanel();
        final JLabel title = new JLabel("Register");
        final JButton button = new JButton("Show");
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            north.add(title);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            reference.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            reference.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

After initialising the rest of the program, simply use the referenced `ValuableList` object to obtain the stored `ArrayList` object.

```
            button.addActionListener(event -> {
                for (final Valuable valuable : register.getList())
                {
                    textArea.append(valuable.toString() + System.lineSeparator());
                    System.out.println(valuable.toString());
                }
            });
            south.add(button);
            reference.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        } else {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                 this.initialiseUserInterface(reference, register);
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And now the `ValuableList` class containing the required `List` object.

```
    public class ValuablesList {
        private final String name;
        private final ArrayList<Valuable> arrayList;

        public ValuablesList(final String name, final int capacity)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public ArrayList<Valuable> getList()
        {
            return this.arrayList;
        }
    }
```

I would highly recommend you to remove the `ValuableList` class, due to the reason that it is redundant. You can just directly use an `ArrayList` to enhance performance and tidy up your code. If you have any questions regarding my answer feel free to comment.